# Why i get undefined when trying to access an object that is returned after a get request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object, undefined

So, I currently work on my first node.js project where I created an api. I would like to create one endpoint, where i would like to give 3 parameters in GET request method: "base" , "target" and "amount", and after retrieving data from mongoDb and apropriate calculations I would  like the response to return the given amount given in target currency! The problem is that to access the ratios I get undefined!

my code for this endpoint is:

```
router.get('/convert', async(req,res)=>{

    let base = req.body.base;
    let target = req.body.target;
    let amount = req.body.amount;


    const getRatios = await Ratios.findOne({base: base});
    if(!getRatios) return res.status(400).send('No such a currency found');

    try{            
        res.send(getRatios.ratios.target);        
    }

    catch(err){

        console.log('something bad happened');
        console.log(getRatios.ratios);
    }

})
```

The only way to reach the values of the stored ratios is in console after I hard code the desired "target" i would like to access! eg `console.log(getRatios.ratios.target)` returns undefined
but `console.log(getRatios.ratios.AUD)` returns the rate for AUD

This only works in console, but when I try to get a response :
`res.send(getRatios.ratios.target)` or `res.send(getRatios.ratios.AUD)` returns nothing!

the `res.send(getRatios.ratios)` works fine and returns:

```
{
    "EUR": 0.82110323,
    "AUD": 1.2923873,
    "JPY": 109.49154,
    "USD": 1,
    "CHF": 0.89690769
}
```

however i would like to get access the object's values!

Comment: Please console log getRatios and send here

Comment: This is the console.log(getRatios) return
 {
  ratios: {
    EUR: 0.82110323,
    AUD: 1.2923873,
    JPY: 109.49154,
    USD: 1,
    CHF: 0.89690769
  },
  _id: 60bfb0508ea40238bca9cdac,
  base: 'USD',
  date: 2021-06-08T18:00:48.700Z,
  __v: 0
}

Comment: Hi Georgios!

What's the type of the getRatios.ratio? (do console.log(typeof getRatios.ratio))

If it's a string, you might need to parse that into an object first JSON.parse(getRatios.ratios)

Also, you're saying that getRatios.AUD returns the rate for AUD, so why not just return that instead of getRatios.ratios.AUD?

Comment: So how will you get getRatios.ratios.target?

Comment: The type of getRatios.ratios in console is Object! I made an edit, in my question i get the rate only in console  when I  try console.log(getRatios.ratios.AUD) which is not what I 'm trying to do! I would like the req.body.target to be the key in the getRatios.ratios object and i would to get the value!! Thank you for the responses !